# How to do setdiff but with repetition in matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, comparison

I have two arrays of different sizes, array `A` and array `B`.

I want to return the indices of the data in `A` that is not in `B` **with repetitions** using Matlab.

In other words, I want a function that is similar to `setdiff` in matlab, but with repeition.

Comment: Can you show us the result of a setdiff with repetition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given A and B (two matrices / row vectors on which you want to perform a row-wise diff, in this example):

```
idx = ~ismember(A,B,'rows');
res = A(idx,:);
```

and if you want the indices too, like in the second output argument of setdiff:

```
res_idx = find(idx);
```

Keep in mind that ismember uses a comparison between values. If A and B contain floating-point numbers with high precision, round them up a little before proceeding.

Reference: https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html

Comment: [`ismembertol`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismembertol.html) allows for set operations with a tolerance.